# Phonegap on iOS - how to get preference to appear in 'Settings' of device

Tags: ios, cordova

On iOS an app's settings can show up in the OS level settings app, outside of the phonegap app.

[image]

In Phonegap, how I can get my app's settings to show up there?

Comment: Ah, Ok, just worked this out! Will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use this plugin

[Application Preferences Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/ApplicationPreferences)

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'm using. What it doesn't seem to do is to make the prefs appear in the generic sttings 'app' of the iPad, i.e. I'd have to make my own edit dialog rather than use the native one.

Comment: Did you create the Root.plist and the settings bundle? Anyways, according to the HIG, apple recommends using this kind of setting, when the user won't frecuently change them

Comment: I did a plist somewhere, not sure about the bundle! (new to Apple). That's given me somewhere to look further thanks. I'll report back!

Comment: OK, got it sorted using http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html   Many thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure whay this was closed - it was a real question and has been answered! Thanks for those who gave positive input ;)

Comment: Maybe those who reported don't know what phonegap is, and didn't understand the question, but it was pretty clear to me. I have upvoted the question.

Comment: Idle hands etc.! Cheers - Martin

Comment: This is a legitimate question. However, the link is now broken.